# Using an API for web based front end as well as iPhone App

Tags: api, rest, laravel

Im using Laravel to create a blogging style system.

My aim in my head is to have a single processing system for all actions that can be used via a REST API.

So for example creating a new blog:

Website:

User fills out form and then clicks create. This calls the route: /api/blog/create

App:

Same again, and the same web url is called: domain.com/api/create

--

Normally on a website I would simply create a new row and then return view('newblog) etc.

But for a app I will want to return JSON.

Whats the best way to go about this? Can I know where the call is coming from and respond differently? Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can check: if the request is an ajax request return json, if not, return view.

```
Route::get('test', function(Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
    if($request->ajax() {
        return response()->json();
    }

    return view();
});
```